# Overlay polygons on raster colour map to extract area values for each colour within each polygon

Tags: raster, polygon, overlay, area

Does anyone know an answer to the following:
I have a set of polygons created as the MCP of animal movements. I also have a habitat colour map raster, with 13 different habitat types as different colours. I need to find a way of overlaying one on the other and calculating the area of each habitat type within each polygon. Possible?
I think it has something to do with overlaying, but have not used it before, and usually asking those who know is far faster than self-discovery!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which software tools do you have available?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified what software you are using, but the general idea is you overlay the layers, perform an intersect and determine the area of the remaining polygon from the intersect.

Answer (score 2):

A couple suggestions: If you'd like to keep your base dataset as a raster, Hawths Tools has a great tool that allows you to clip a raster dataset by a polygon. If not, just convert your raster to a polygon and perform a union of the two datasets.

Answer (score 1):

SAGA GIS has a "Raster statistics"-Module for shape areas ontop of raster files.