# Extract values based on raster colour in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, overlay, extract

I have a shapefile layer of postal codes in The Netherlands. I also have a energy consumption colour map raster, with different energy types as different colours. I need to find a way of overlaying one on the other and extract the postal codes underneath the raster. So I want to extract each postal code that's coloured blue.

[image]

Comment: See here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/434966/88814

Comment: Seems neither specific to the netherlands nor to postal codes, therefore remove the tags.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to GIS.SE! The tool you are looking for is called "Zonal statistics" and can be found under "Raster analysis" in the Processing Toolbox:

[image]

Select your shape layer with the parcels as `Input layer` and your `Raster layer` (likely one with classes not with bands like in my sample case):

[image]

as well as the statistics to calculate (I think `Mean` and `Majority` might make sense in this case):

[image]

The resulting vector layer has the statistics as attributes

[image]

that can be used for further analysis etc.

In this sample case (labeled with fid's) consider the hight majority values in the blue chanel, so you would have fid=5,9 (or postal codes rsp.):

[image]

Related: [Overlay polygons on raster colour map to extract area values for each colour within each polygon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8640/overlay-polygons-on-raster-colour-map-to-extract-area-values-for-each-colour-wit)